# Filhos de um seletor: um com margin left outro com right

Tags: css

Seguinte, sempre tive essa dúvida
tenho essa estrutura html

```
<!-- wrap1 -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="filho">
    (...)
  </div>
</div>

<!-- wrap2 -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="filho">
    (...)
  </div>
</div>
```

Sei que posso fazer isso de outras formas, mas gostaria de saber posso selecionar o .wrap .filho(do primeiro) e fazer com que ele receba margin left e o .wrap .filho (do segundo) receba margin right? O cenário é exatamente esse. Obrigado a quem puder me esclarecer.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Poderia explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível usando a *pseudo-class* `:nth-child`:

```css
.wrap:nth-child(1) .filho{
   margin-left: 50px;
}

.wrap:nth-child(2) .filho{
   margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- wrap1 -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="filho">
    (...)
  </div>
</div>

<!-- wrap2 -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="filho">
    (...)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, testei aqui e funcionou. Gostei dessa solução pois ela soa "elegante e legível" no código.